# How to do Queries Performance Load Testing on HBase via Phoenix especailly for Multi-tenant?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, database-performance, multi-tenant, apache-phoenix

I was trying to use JMeter to do this task, but it didn't work. I was trying to add xml file via user.properties from JMeter /bin dir, and parse the user.properties in it. This way is successful for parsing the namespace when I trying to connect with HBase via Phoenix. But this time, it was failed when I wanted to parse the TenantId.. Anyone has idea for that? Or any other tool can do the performance load testing for queries?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you're trying to achieve, just in case be aware that there is a [Hadoop Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HadoopSet/) of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which provides the following custom Test Elements:

- [HBase Connection Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseConnection/) where you can define Zookeeper host and connection name
- [HBase CRUD Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseCRUDSampler/) for testing create/read/update/delete operations
- [HBase Scan Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HBaseScanSampler/) for retrieving data from the HBase

You can install Hadoop Set of JMeter Plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Hadoop]

If you need to override any setting you can do it "normally" using JMeter Properties and/or variables.

Comment: If I wanted to test the multi-tenancy from Phoenix. For instance, I had a table, it has two TenantId: BOA and Chase from it. And I only wanted to test the TenantId as Chase. In DBeaver, IF I wanted to use multi-tenancy, I just needed to add TenantId as Chase inside user.properties and it worked. How can I do this in JMeter?

Comment: The thing I wanted to achieve is that I wanted to test those queries' performance load testing using multi-tenancy, the Phoenix features. So I wanted to test those queries only for one specific TenantId, not for all of the data, just for the specific column for the required TenantId.